# Custom Devise routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, devise, routes

```
Using devise (3.2.2)
Using rails (4.0.2)
```

Working on developing an API which only has the need for only certain routes. I have the following in my `routes.rb`:

```
devise_for :users, path: '/users', controllers: {
  sessions: 'v1/custom_devise/sessions',
  passwords: 'v1/custom_devise/passwords'
}
```

Great! Now we have all these routes:

```
              Prefix Verb    URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    new_user_session GET     /users/sign_in(.:format)       v1/custom_devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)       v1/custom_devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)      v1/custom_devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST    /users/password(.:format)      v1/custom_devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET     /users/password/new(.:format)  v1/custom_devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET     /users/password/edit(.:format) v1/custom_devise/passwords#edit
                     PATCH   /users/password(.:format)      v1/custom_devise/passwords#update
                     PUT     /users/password(.:format)      v1/custom_devise/passwords#update
```

But I do not want or need these routes:

```
    new_user_session GET     /users/sign_in(.:format)       v1/custom_devise/sessions#new
   new_user_password GET     /users/password/new(.:format)  v1/custom_devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET     /users/password/edit(.:format) v1/custom_devise/passwords#edit
```

So I thought I will just create my own routes as per the documentation. So I changed my `routes.rb`:

```
devise_scope :user do
  post   '/users/sign_in'  => 'custom_devise/sessions#create',  as: :user_session
  delete '/users/sign_out' => 'custom_devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session

  post  '/users/password'  => 'custom_devise/passwords#create', as: :user_password
  put   '/users/password'  => 'custom_devise/passwords#update', as: nil
  patch '/users/password'  => 'custom_devise/passwords#update', as: nil
end
```

Now my routes look perfect, just the way I want them:

```
              Prefix Verb    URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
        user_session POST    /users/sign_in(.:format)      v1/custom_devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session DELETE  /users/sign_out(.:format)     v1/custom_devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST    /users/password(.:format)     v1/custom_devise/passwords#create
                     PUT     /users/password(.:format)     v1/custom_devise/passwords#update
                     PATCH   /users/password(.:format)     v1/custom_devise/passwords#update
```

But now my requests fail, with:

```
 AbstractController::ActionNotFound:
   Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/sign_in".
   This may happen for two reasons:

   1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example:

     devise_scope :user do
       get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller"
     end

   2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
      If so, you can explicitly tell Devise which mapping to use:

      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
```

I have tried many variations, to no avail.

**UPDATE:** This may be overkill, but here is an sample example app demonstration this. Not sure if I am doing something wrong or if this might be a devise bug.

Sample App: https://github.com/michaelirey/devise_weird

Comment: `"/users/sign_in"` is for devise session new so you will need the `new_user_session` route.

Comment: @CharlesJHardy: the `GET` request for `/users/sign_in` is not needed as this is an API.

Comment: Are these failures happening in tests or in development?

Comment: @LouisSimoneau: development

Comment: I cloned the sample app and it runs just fine.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the **GET** for the sign in action that shows you the login form.. you only have the session creation, fix it like such (you :

```
devise_scope :user do
  get   '/users/sign_in'  => 'custom_devise/sessions#new',  as: :new_user_session      
  post   '/users/sign_in'  => 'custom_devise/sessions#create',  as: :user_session
  delete '/users/sign_out' => 'custom_devise/sessions#destroy', as: :destroy_user_session

  post  '/users/password'  => 'custom_devise/passwords#create', as: :user_password
  put   '/users/password'  => 'custom_devise/passwords#update', as: nil
  patch '/users/password'  => 'custom_devise/passwords#update', as: nil
end
```

Comment: Not sure if this answers the posted question or not, but definitely helped me with the problem that landed me on this page. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

BTW Separately from this question, the OP got movement on this issue here:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2840

This may explain why it worked in August 2014 after failing in January 2014.

The thread's closing comments are:

> This should help anyone in 2016
>   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063026/how-do-i-override-devise-controller-and-devise-routes-at-the-same-time

And:

> anyone still facing this issue even after doing
>
> `devise_for :users, skip: :all devise_scope :user do end`
>
> please refer to this issue [#2496](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/2496#issuecomment-20645182) if you're calling
>   devise_scope inside a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my working example of how to solve this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  # This is the fix.
  devise_for :users, skip: :all

  devise_scope :user do
    get "/users/sign_in", to: "devise/sessions#new", as: :new_user_session
    post "/users/sign_in", to: "devise/sessions#create", as: :user_session
    delete "/users/sign_out", to: "devise/sessions#destroy", as: :destroy_user_session
    get "/users/password/new", to: "devise/passwords#new", as: :new_user_password
    get "/users/password/edit", to: "devise/passwords#edit", as: :edit_user_password

    patch "/users/password", to: "devise/passwords#update", as: :user_password
    put "/users/password", to: "devise/passwords#update"
    post "/users/password", to: "devise/passwords#create"

    get "/users/cancel", to: "devise/registrations#cancel", as: :cancel_user_registration
    get "/users/sign_up", to: "devise/registrations#new", as: :new_user_registration
    get "/users/edit", to: "devise/registrations#edit", as: :edit_user_registration

    patch "/users", to: "devise/registrations#update", as: :user_registration
    put "/users", to: "devise/registrations#update"
    delete "/users", to: "devise/registrations#destroy"
    post "/users", to: "devise/registrations#create"
  end
end
```

Thanks for the hint, GuyPaddock. Figured I'd post this as a separate answer because your answer doesn't have a full code example, and doesn't explicitly state that this is a solution.