# Rails: How do I override Devise controller and Devise routes at the same time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I am using Rails 4.0.2 and Devise 3.2.2 to handle user registration / authentication.

I have googled and search stackoverflow for answers, can't really find something that can answer my question.

The below code is my **routes.rb**,  I have skip all sessions routes and registration routes but for some reason, Devise is not using my custom **registrations_controller.rb** because if it is, it should redirect to /pages/success  (please see below my registrations_controller.rb )

### routes.rb

```
App::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :posts
  resources :questions
  get "users/:id", to: "users#show" 

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}, :skip =>     [:sessions, :registrations]


  as :user do
    get 'login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post 'login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    delete 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
  end


  as :user do
    get '/' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
    post 'register' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
  end

  get "registrations/update"
  get "pages/home"
  get "pages/privacy"
  get "pages/terms"
  get "pages/success"

end
```

### registrations_controller.rb

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

protected

  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    '/pages/success'
  end

end
```

Comment: how do you know it's not using it, what do your logs say its doing after you perform an inactive signup?

Comment: If I exclude the `:skip` and all the custom routes, it will redirect to '/pages/success'

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are several potential issues you may have:

---

**Skip**

If you're skipping the registrations functionality, I'd imagine it would prevent Devise from calling your `RegistrationsController`?

I would personally do this (correct your routes):

```
#config/routes.rb
root to: "users#index" (where ever your "logged-in" page is)

devise_for :users, path: "", controllers: { sessions: "sessions", registrations: "registrations" }, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', password: 'forgot', confirmation: 'confirm', unlock: 'unblock', sign_up: 'register', sign_out: 'signout'}
```

This will give you the routes you need, and will route to the "authenticated" index page in your app, thus either showing the login or registration page for Devise

---

**Definition**

The other issue you may have is an incorrect definition of your Devise Registrations controller. We use this code in a very recent development app:

```
#app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < ::Devise::RegistrationsController
end
```

Perhaps you could try using the `::` before your `Devise::RegistrationsController` to see if it calls?

Comment: Oh YES! this line `devise_for :users, path: "", controllers: { sessions: "sessions", registrations: "registrations" }, path_names: { sign_in: 'login', password: 'forgot', confirmation: 'confirm', unlock: 'unblock', sign_up: 'register', sign_out: 'signout'}` fixed the problem,   btw, adding `::` before my `Devise::RegistrationsController` doesn't call. CHEERS MAN!

Comment: Sorry, i can't cos i don't have enough reputation points, i need 15. do you mind vote up my question? haha  Thanks

Comment: There you go buddy - hope it helps!

Comment: Cheers, once i got 15 points, i will come back and vote up ur answer. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance of my answer :) Hope everything works out for you!

Comment: Hi, what about overriding controllers two times for the same recource class? How to setup routes? with `devise_for` or only manually?