# Rails new path in nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I've got controller below controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    module Account
      class PasswordsController < Devise::PasswordsController
        respond_to :json

        def create
         # some code
        end

        def update
         # some code
        end

        def is_token_valid
          ::Account.find_by(reset_password_token: params[:token])
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I want to setup an endpoint for front-end dev where he will check if `reset_password_token` exist in DB (devise here). I don't know how to made a path like: `/api/v1/account/password/is_token_valid`

My routes:

```
namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do
    namespace :v1 do
      namespace :account do
        devise_for :accounts, singular: 'account', path: '', controllers: {
          sessions:      'api/v1/account/sessions',
          registrations: 'api/v1/account/registrations',
          confirmations: 'api/v1/account/confirmations',
          passwords:     'api/v1/account/passwords',
        }
      end

      resource :account, only: [:show]
```

EDIT

routes:

```
  root@b2faabb49f91:/usr/src/app# rake routes | grep account
                         new_account_session GET    /api/v1/account/sign_in(.:format)                                                        api/v1/account/sessions#new {:format=>:json}
                             account_session POST   /api/v1/account/sign_in(.:format)                                                        api/v1/account/sessions#create {:format=>:json}
                     destroy_account_session DELETE /api/v1/account/sign_out(.:format)                                                       api/v1/account/sessions#destroy {:format=>:json}
                        new_account_password GET    /api/v1/account/password/new(.:format)                                                   api/v1/account/passwords#new {:format=>:json}
                       edit_account_password GET    /api/v1/account/password/edit(.:format)                                                  api/v1/account/passwords#edit {:format=>:json}
                            account_password PATCH  /api/v1/account/password(.:format)                                                       api/v1/account/passwords#update {:format=>:json}
```

Comment: Devise already has a built in `GET /resource/password/edit?reset_password_token=abcdef` route (which is the link sent out in the mail) route. Do you really need one more?

Comment: I'm trying to test this devise endpoint in postman with token generated in the mail but nothing is returned - `204 No Content` all the time. That's why I decided to create new one.

Comment: What does `rails routes` tell you?

Comment: @max routes added

Comment: Its `GET /api/v1/account/password/edit`.

Comment: Does this help? -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/22063874/1737811

Comment: @max exactly and I'm getting `204 No Content` in case when `reset_password_token` is a random number like `1234` and the same when I provide valid token from DB

Comment: Sorry my brain is still asleep. 204 is completely normal and its because the edit route does pretty much nothing - it just renders a form and its not really intended to be used with json. You can just implement your own `edit` method in the controller. Alternatively you can create your own route with `devise_scope`.

Comment: Ok, thanks @max I will override `edit` action as you suggested